# Tomcat: Creating a connection pool for cloud API services

Tags: tomcat, concurrency, connection-pooling, tomcat9, connection-pool

A Tomcat server worker thread replying to an incoming request must access at least one of several possible cloud API services (Google Cloud Storage in particular; non-modifying, that is, only performing Reads). Tomcat offers out-of-the-box pooling for JDBC and JNDI compatible DB's and services. What is the best strategy for pooling connections to multiple cloud services to be shared across worker threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned Tomcat allows defining [JDBC/JNDI resources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Code_Example) that can be [used by web applications](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#PostgreSQL). If there is a JDBC driver available for the service you want to use then you can use the same approach. For example, a quick search for GCS JDBC driver returns [this](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/googlecloudstorage/jdbc/).

For pooling, you could define [HikariCP as a tomcat resource](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/tomcat-hikaricp) and configure it to connect to GCS using the third-party driver using the `driverClassName` property.

Alternatively, applications can use the [HTTP-based SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) that cloud providers usually make available.

Comment: how does this answer to the need of **pooling** the connections ?

Comment: For pooling, you could define [HikariCP as a tomcat resource](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/tomcat-hikaricp) and configure it to connect to GCS using the third-party driver using the `driverClassName` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your application access API over HTTP(S). The connection pooling must be performed at HTTP Client level.

If you're using [Apache HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/quickstart.html), there are [examples](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/0a42d173ef7ae4497439cf52d75d43ef51e46541/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/io/TestPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java#L91) of usage of pool.